# Using VEMap to color a region

Tags: mapping, bing-maps, virtual-earth, vwdexpress

Using visual web developer express 2010, I want to display a shape file and be able to manipulate the colors of the regions specified by that shape file based on some data values.

I found some code (I think it was an MSDN page) that throws up a simple map on to the screen of a web page.  Here it is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function OnPageLoad() {
          map = new VEMap('myMap');
          map.LoadMap();

      }
  </script>

<body onload="OnPageLoad();">
  <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:640px;height:480px;"></div>
```

It doesn't use a shapefile, per se, but something online that it's pointing to (Virtual Earth).  that's okay, that might work, but ...

It displays a map with some basic control mechanisms (pan, zoom, etc.).  I copy-pasted this into a web page and it works well.  I want to be able to color regions on this map based on some values.  I figure there's got to be some kind of underlying structure to this thing (an object model) that contains references to the regions, etc.  But I can get any help from intellisense in visual web developer express 2010.

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Meanwhile, back to searching the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 6.3 I believe you do this with the [VEShape Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412535.aspx).

Here are the [classes supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429565.aspx) for 6.3.

These are some great [examples](http://www.garzilla.net/vemaps/Draggable-Polygon-with-Bing-Maps-7.aspx) to get you started.  Although a lot of them are version 7.0 but the syntax is quite similar.  If your having troubles converting, here is a nice [migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237870.aspx)  from 6.3 to 7.0 provided by msdn.